# Pegar informações do Browser em Procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, procedure

É possível pegar informações do navegador em uma **PROCEDURE** via código MySQL?

Sem que seja necessário pegar via código back-end e passar como parâmetro.
Ou seja, o MySQL possui alguma função que retorno informações do navegador?

Comment: acredito que nao, por que o mysql é executado no seu servidor entao ele nem sabe quem fez a solicitacao, se foi pelo navegador, o php, java ou direto no console do mysql, pra ele tanto faz de onde veio.

Comment: Então @NeuberOliveira, eu tenho essa dúvida. Porque como ele tem a referencia do IP do usuário que fez a ação, pensei que talvez ele também tenha as informações do navegador. Mas não consegui achar nada sobre.

Comment: Esse ip que ele tem ou é do seu servidor que fez a requisição, no caso seu servidor php, ou então foi alguma informação que vc passou através da sua aplicação para o banco

Comment: Sim @JefersonAlmeida, através da função: "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', -1)" ele me retorna o endereço de IPV4 do usuário que fez a ação.

Comment: @alan mas esse endereço ip não é o endereço do seu servidor php que fez a requisição ao banco ou é o ip do usuário que fez alguma ação na pagina?

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida É o ipv4 do usuario, o ip dele de acesso a internet. Esse ip é único para cada usuário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é um erro conceitual seu. O MySQL precisa de um servidor para rodar, ou seja, de um computador, que é um nó na rede de computadores.

O browser precisa de um computador para rodar, que também é um nó na rede.

Cada nó tem um "nome" único, que é o IP. Os nós podem ser roteadores, *bridges*, *laptops*, *mainframes*, enfim, qualquer coisa que possa ser conectada a uma rede de computadores, até mesmo sub-redes.

O seu navegador não possui um IP, quem possui é seu computador.

SQL **pode** ser considerada uma [linguagem de domínio específico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_dom%C3%ADnio_espec%C3%ADfico) e é usada principalmente para manipular dados em bancos de dados relacionais.

Nada impede, no entanto, que a equipe que desenvolve o MySQL venha um dia usar a principal tecnologia (C++) do SGBD para pegar mais informações do cliente ao acessar um servidor MySQL, desde que autorizado pelo usuário.